# How to make a tkinter window Fullscreen on all Displays?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a program with a window that needs to be fullscreen on **all** plugged-in Monitors and/or external displays. Is there any way I can do this in Tkinter or do I have to use a different library? So far I have managed to get the window in Fullscreen on my main display but I also need it on the other one(s). This is my code so far:

```
def create_screencanvas():
    global master_screen
    master_screen = Toplevel(mywindow)
    picture_frame = Frame(master_screen, background = "blue")
    picture_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    global screenCanvas
    screenCanvas = Canvas(picture_frame, cursor="cross", bg="grey5")
    screenCanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    master_screen.attributes('-fullscreen', True)#Fullscreen on main display but not others
    master_screen.attributes('-alpha', .3)
    master_screen.lift()
    master_screen.attributes("-topmost", True)

mywindow = Tk()
mywindow.title("New Project") 
mywindow.geometry("780x640") 
mywindow.minsize(540, 420) 
mywindow.configure(bg="blue") 

mybtn = Button(text="activate", command=create_screencanvas, cursor="cross")
mybtn.pack() #Button opens the fullscrean window

mywindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by on all displays? Do you want the window to spread over all displays or to see the same window duplicated on each display? You can change the geometry of the window to cover the full extent of the displays, using `.winfo_screenheight()` and `.winfo_screenwidth()` but if your displays do not form a rectangle,  part of the window will not be visible.

Comment: Both works but probably the second option

Comment: Actually the second one is probably better

Comment: One problem with spreading a display over many monitors is the issue of resolution between each monitor. If they are different you wont be able to easily expand between them. I think your only real solution is to have your display duplicate over multiple monitors however that is not an easy task either since you will need to figure out do you want each displace to be able to interact with the window or not and if so that presents a new issue with managing each even from each window.

Comment: I think your question needs a little more context.
Why exactly do you need to have your application display on all monitors or do you simple need to a blank screen on all monitors except for the main monitor? What is the desired outcome.

Comment: Well, I am working on a click-and-drag screenshot tool in Tkinter. And the way I do it is that I have a semi-transparent window on which I draw a rectangle and take the screenshot using the rectangle coordinates. The area where you can take screenshots needs to obviously be the entire desktop so you can take a picture of anything on any of the screens. Basically, I'm recreating the windows WIN+SHIFT+S functions in python and Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

For screenshot taking purposes, you can make your `Toplevel` window cover all the displays by changing manually its geometry instead of making it fullscreen. So, remove

```
master_screen.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

and replace it with

```
w = master_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
h = master_screen.winfo_screenheight()
master_screen.geometry(f"{w}x{h}+0+0")
```

However, your window now has unwanted decorations. Depending on the OS you are using, you can either use

```
master_screen.overrideredirect(True)
```

or, if you are using Linux (in which case, `overrideredirect` might not allow you to have window transparency),

```
master_screen.attributes('-type', 'dock')
```

In both cases, you no longer need

```
master_screen.attributes("-topmost", True)
```